# adb device not found after reboot

Tags: adb, reboot, shell

I am developing an automated test script to turn off my android device and turn it on back again and then run a few adb commands after the boot is complete.

My problem is that when I turn the device off and turn it on back again, the `sys.boot_completed` flag is true , showing that the device is on, but any command such as `adb  -s <device_id> shell` returns a device not found error.

I tried inserting delays between commands and sleep for boot completion but this error sometimes shows up after a few reboot cycles.

Is there a way to automize reboot with some post-reboot sanity check ?

Comment: check the device's usb connection mode. enable MTP and try.

Comment: it is actually an Android TV, I am afraid I cant do that.